# Add active class based on child <a> href

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have such nav stucture:

```
<ul class="page-sidebar-menu">
  <li class="menu">        
    <a href="">
      <span class="title">Menu Item</span>
      <span class="arrow"></span>
    </a>    
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="somehref">Sub Menu Item</a>
      </li>
    </ul>                   
  </li>
</ul>
```

To highlight the submenu link I need to add active class to '.submenu li'
Also I want to add active class to 'li.menu' depending on '.submenu li a' href
Tried to do such like this but it's not working:

```
  $(function(){
    var current = location.pathname;
    current = current.substring(current.lastIndexOf('/'));
    $('.sub-menu li a').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){
            $('.sub-menu:parent').addClass('start active open'); //ISSUE
            $('.sub-menu li a:parent').addClass('active');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use current iteration context `this` to target current anchor and use `.closest()`  to traverse to required parent element `.sub-menu`. and then add required classes to them:

```
 $('.sub-menu li a').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){
        $this.closest('.sub-menu').addClass('start active open'); //ISSUE
        $this.addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: it's not working for me :(

Comment: @kipris: working demo.

Comment: my project a bit harder because I used Angular (for url changing) http://plnkr.co/edit/pggakYtKS9xgxeMuKPEC?p=preview

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7pyhacpc/

Comment: @kipris: like this http://jsfiddle.net/y5mmdq7q/

Comment: I got it already, thanks :)